# How to create a view that show last 4 quarters data?

Tags: mysql, sql

My environment is  5.1.72-community.

I have a table named production, like:

```
 id, person_id, num, p_year, p_quarter
 1, 1, 43, 2018, 2 
 2, 1, 92, 2018, 1
 3, 1, 108, 2017, 4
 4, 2, 41, 2018, 2
 ...
```

By the time of '2018-04-14', we know quarter=2, and year=2018. I define quarter_1 is current quarter of current year, and quarter_2 is previous quarter, ans so on. Now I want to create a view like:

```
 person_id, num_quarter_1, num_quarter_2, num_quarter_3, num_quarter_4
 1, 43, 92, 108, 0
 2, 41, 0, 0, 0
```

As that, if there no num in that quarter, fill 0.

How to create that view please?

Comment: You would be better off storing your date information as _dates_, not as separate year and quarter.

Comment: What does "last four quarters" mean?  The most recent 4 that are in the data?  Based on time?  For each person?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I interpret that to mean the most recent four quarters up to, and including now.  But that year and quarter are separate numbers makes not feel like doing SQL olympics right now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, but I need the year and quarter as unique index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I do not describe it clearly. it means by the natural time, if now is '2018-04-14', the last 4 quarters is: 2018-Q2, 2018-Q1, 2017-Q4, 2017-Q3. if now is '2017-09-10', the last 4 quarters is: 2017-Q3, 2017-Q2, 2017-Q1, 2016-Q4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  If I interpret "last four quarters" as "the last four quarters that are in the data", then here is one method.

First, you can get the four quarters by doing:

```
select distinct p_year, p_quarter
from production p
order by p_year desc, p_quarter desc
limit 4;
```

You can enumerate them using variables:

```
select p_year, p_quarter, (@rn := @rn + 1) as enum
from (select distinct p_year, p_quarter
      from production p
      order by p_year desc, p_quarter desc
      limit 4
     ) p cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
```

Then, you can use this in a query to pivot the data:

```
select p.person_id,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 3 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_3,
       sum(case when seqnum = 4 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_4
from production p join
     (select p_year, p_quarter, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from (select distinct p_year, p_quarter
            from production p
            order by p_year desc, p_quarter desc
            limit 4
           ) p cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) yq
     using (p_year, p_quarter)
group by p.person_id;
```

EDIT:

If you are defining the quarters based on the current quarter, you can do something quite similar:

```
select p.person_id,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 3 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_3,
       sum(case when seqnum = 4 then num else 0 end) as num_quarter_4
from production p join
     (select year(curdate()) as p_year, quarter(curdate()) as p_quarter, 1 as seqnum union all
      select year(curdate() - interval 1 quarter) as p_year, month(curdate() - interval 1 quarter) as p_quarter, 2 as seqnum union all
      select year(curdate() - interval 2 quarter) as p_year, month(curdate() - interval 2 quarter) as p_quarter, 3 as seqnum union all
      select year(curdate() - interval 2 quarter) as p_year, month(curdate() - interval 3 quarter) as p_quarter, 4 as seqnum           
     ) yq
     using (p_year, p_quarter)
group by p.person_id;
```

There are other approaches, such as:

```
select person_id,
       sum(case when year(curdate()) = p_year and quarter(curdate()) = p_quarter
                then num else 0
           end) as num_quarter_1,
       sum(case when year(curdate() - interval 1 quarter) = p_year and quarter(curdate() - interval 1 quarter) = p_quarter
                then num else 0
           end) as num_quarter_2,
       sum(case when year(curdate() - interval 2 quarter) = p_year and quarter(curdate() - interval 2 quarter) = p_quarter
                then num else 0
           end) as num_quarter_3,
       sum(case when year(curdate() - interval 3 quarter) = p_year and quarter(curdate() - interval 3 quarter) = p_quarter
                then num else 0
           end) as num_quarter_4
from production p
group by person_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I know it now. and I will put yq in a view too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    person_id,
    SUM((p_quarter = 1) * num) as num_quarter_1,
    SUM((p_quarter = 2) * num) as num_quarter_2,
    SUM((p_quarter = 3) * num) as num_quarter_3,
    SUM((p_quarter = 4) * num) as num_quarter_4
FROM production
WHERE p_year = 2018
GROUP BY person_id;
```