# How to use regexp in procedure with mariadb please?

Tags: regex, mariadb, procedure

My environment:

windows 7 sp1 64bit

mariadb 10.3.8

I create a procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `num_of_zone`(IN zone_reg varchar(1000))
BEGIN
  DECLARE person_num INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO person_num FROM person WHERE address REGEXP zone_reg;
  SELECT person_num FROM DUAL;
END;
```

And now I call it, the cpu goto 100%, later, my mariadb service will be stopped.
But if I run the sql with specific zone_reg like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO person_num FROM person WHERE address REGEXP 'River [1-4]U.*';
```

it will be good.

What is my wrong please?

My test db and datas:

```
CREATE TABLE flup_person (
  person_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  flup_year int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  flup_quarter int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW yq AS
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) AS flup_year, QUARTER(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS flup_quarter
UNION
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) AS flup_year, QUARTER(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) AS flup_quarter
UNION
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 QUARTER) AS flup_year, QUARTER(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 QUARTER) AS flup_quarter
UNION
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 QUARTER) AS flup_year, QUARTER(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 QUARTER) AS flup_quarter;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW flup_view AS
SELECT p.person_id, p.address
FROM flup_person AS p LEFT JOIN yq
USING (flup_year, flup_quarter)
GROUP BY p.person_id;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE num_of_zone(IN zone_reg varchar(1000))
BEGIN
  DECLARE person_num int;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO person_num FROM flup_view WHERE address REGEXP zone_reg;
  SELECT person_num FROM DUAL;
END;

INSERT INTO flup_person(person_id, address, flup_year, flup_quarter)
VALUES
(2, 'River 1Uz', 2018, 1),
(3, 'River 2Uz', 2018, 3),
(4, 'River 15Ud', 2018, 2);
```

Last, I use:

```
CALL num_of_zone('River [1-2].*');
```

It will stop the mariadb.

But use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flup_view WHERE address REGEXP 'River [1-2].*';
```

It is ok.

Comment: What is inside `zone_reg` when it freezes the system?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use SELECT zone_reg FROM DUAL; in procedure, it is "River [1-4]U.*" (no quotes).

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: What did `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` say?  I'm curious as to whether it substituted correctly.

Comment: @RickJames SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; say nothing, the service was stopped, and nothing useful in the .err file. ~14k rows in testdb. I try it in some simple table or view, it is ok. but in some complex view(with union, group see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831313/how-to-create-a-view-that-show-last-4-quarters-data), it is not ok.

Comment: @RickJames I put a simple test under my question. that procedure will stop mariadb.

Comment: Please write a bug report to MariaDB.